# ZFS Scrub isn't making any progress

Tags: opensolaris, zfs

I started a `zfs scrub` operation over 10 hours ago, and it doesn't seem to be making any progress:

```
# zpool status
  pool: foo
 state: ONLINE
 scan: scrub in progress since Sat Nov 26 00:11:38 2011
    1 scanned out of 1.58T at 1/s, 481199724h39m to go
    0 repaired, 0.00% done
config:

        NAME        STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
        foo         ONLINE       0     0     0
          raidz1-0  ONLINE       0     0     0
            c1t3d0  ONLINE       0     0     0
            c1t2d0  ONLINE       0     0     0
            c1t4d0  ONLINE       0     0     0

errors: No known data errors
```

Is it possible that it's actually making progress but not reporting it?  Any way I can get further information about what's going on?

**Should I be concerned about this?**

Comment: Maybe Sun or Oracle took the time estimation formula from Microsoft's Internet Explorer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Three days later, the `zfs scrub` is finished.  No progress was indicated until about 24 hours into the process.

```
# zpool status
  pool: foo
 state: ONLINE
 scan: scrub repaired 0 in 79h37m with 0 errors on Tue Nov 29 07:48:43 2011
config:

        NAME        STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
        foo         ONLINE       0     0     0
          raidz1-0  ONLINE       0     0     0
            c1t3d0  ONLINE       0     0     0
            c1t2d0  ONLINE       0     0     0
            c1t4d0  ONLINE       0     0     0

errors: No known data errors
```

Comment: This is normal, depending in large part on the size of the pool and available system resources.